# Android rawQuery GUI to check query

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging

Having a confounding problem with a query that worked for a while and then stopped working. With a try and catch, there is no error it just returns a null cursor?
Is there a GUI where you can run the query to check the result first or see an error, perhaps it is something subtle like keys? I have confirmed the data types but don't know where else to look. I have concerns going forward on how to debug this type of issue so would appreciate any direction you can offer.
Thanks in advance.

The code set works fine on a single table but when I join 2 tables it now fails (worked yesterday)

**Working:**

```
String selectQuery = 
    SELECT ou.*,"name" as Orchard_Name FROM " + TABLE_TP_ORCHARD_USER ou ;
```

**not working** in this case a joined query :

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  ou.tp_orchard_user_Orchard_ID as 
           tp_orchard_user_Orchard_ID,ou.tp_orchard_user_User_ID as 
           tp_orchard_user_User_ID,sd.Orchard_Name as Orchard_Name FROM " + 
           TABLE_TP_ORCHARD_USER + " ou JOIN " + TABLE_SD_ORCHARD + " sd  on
           ou.tp_orchard_user_Orchard_ID=sd.Orchard_Id" ;
```

I have run this code in mysql on another DB and it is fine; it seems maybe there is another error that eclipse can't display? Or I don't know how?

My code sample is:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor daCursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
if (daCursor != null) {  
        if(  daCursor.moveToFirst()  ){
        do{
  //      String Orchard_ID = 
                   daCursor.getString(daCursor.getColumnIndex("Orchard_Id"));
            String Orchard_ID =     daCursor.getString(0);
        Log.i("dbhandler fetchAllOrchards cursor Orchard_ID",
                                                          Orchard_ID);

                Log.i("dbhandler fetchAllOrchards cursor Orchard_ID",
                                                            Orchard_Name);
        } while (daCursor.moveToNext()); 

    } else{
        Log.i("cursor is false","fail");    
    }
}
```

Comment: adb shell, sqlite3 /data/data/<your_package>/databases/<your_db>.db

Comment: That's a good way to look at the db as it exists on your device. If you don't have root, you might have to copy it to external storage first, from in code. Also, the path can differ by device. You can get it in code and log it, so you can copy-paste it into the shell or copy it out to external storage: `Log.d("Here's the database path", context.getDatabasePath(sqliteOpenHelper.getDatabaseName()));`.